# Tried to do a clock in Arduino on my ESP8266 with WS2812

Tags: arduino

I'm new in programming, and tried to programm a clock with a RGB-LED-Ring, but i had Errors and just didn't understand them.
At first i tried it with extra Methods but i didn't really understand how they work so i just wrote the code in the loop.
Would be nice if somebody can help and write beginner friendly.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__

#endif

#define PIN        4


#define NUMPIXELS 24 // Popular NeoPixel ring size
#define Tag
#define STUNDEN
#define MINUTEN
#define SEKUNDEN
#define MULTIRSEK //Multiplikator für die Sekunden
#define MULTIMIN  //Multiplikator für die Minuten
#define MULTISTU  //Multiplikator für die Stunden
static int TAG = 0;
static int STUNDEN = 0;
static int MINUTEN = 0;
static int SEKUNDEN = 0;
static int MULTISEK = 0;
static int MULTIMIN = 0;
static int MULTISTU = 0;

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

#define DELAYVAL 500 // Time (in milliseconds) to pause between pixels

void setup() {
  pixels.begin(); // INITIALIZE NeoPixel strip object (REQUIRED)
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  SEKUNDEN = SEKUNDEN + 1; //Die Uhr die läuft
  if (SEKUNDEN = 60 * MULTISEK) {
    MINUTEN = MINUTEN++;
    MULTISEK = MULTISEK++;
  }
  if (MINUTEN = 60 * MULTIMIN) {
    STUNDEN = STUNDEN++;
    MULTIMIN = MULTIMIN++;
  }
  if (STUNDEN = 60 * MULTISTU) {
    STUNDEN = STUNDEN++;
    MULTISTU = MULTISTU++;
  }
  if (Stunden = 24) {
    Tag = 0
          STUNDEN = 0;
    MINUTEN = 0;
    SEKUNDEN = 0;
    MULTIRSEK = 1; //Multiplikator für die Sekunden
    MULTIMIN = 1; //Multiplikator für die Minuten
    MULTISTU = 1; //Multiplikator für die Stunden
  }

  pixels.clear(); // Set all pixel colors to 'off'

  // The first NeoPixel in a strand is #0, second is 1, all the way up
  // to the count of pixels minus one.

  // pixels.Color() takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255

  pixels.setPixelColor(STUNDEN, pixels.Color(0, 150, 0));

  pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

  delay(DELAYVAL); // Pause before next pass through loop
}
}

void clock() {
  delay(1000);
  SEKUNDEN = SEKUNDEN + 1 //Die Uhr die läuft
  if (SEKUNDEN = 60 * MULTISEK) {
    MINUTEN ++;
    MULTISEK ++;
  }
  if (MINUTEN = 60 * MULTIMIN) {
    STUNDEN ++;
    MULTIMIN ++;
  }
  if (STUNDEN = 60 * MULTISTU) {
    STUNDEN ++;
    MULTISTU ++;
  }
  if (Stunden = 24) {
    Tag 0
    STUNDEN 0;
    MINUTEN 0;
    SEKUNDEN 0;
    MULTIRSEK 1; //Multiplikator für die Sekunden
    MULTIMIN 1; //Multiplikator für die Minuten
    MULTISTU 1; //Multiplikator für die Stunden
  }
}
void reset() {
  Tag 0
  STUNDEN 0;
  MINUTEN 0;
  SEKUNDEN 0;
  MULTIRSEK 1; //Multiplikator für die Sekunden
  MULTIMIN 1; //Multiplikator für die Minuten
  MULTISTU 1; //Multiplikator für die Stunden
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't go into too much details here. Please do a beginners tutorial on C++ befor you continue. You don't need to go into advanced topics like templates or polymorphims yet but at least you should know the basic syntax.

Your code does not make any sense.

What is `#define MULTISEK` supposed to do?

Especially followed by `static int MULTISEK = 0;`

Why do you use preprocessor directives if you don't know what they do?

```
if (Stunden = 24)
```

`=` is the assignment operator. You want to use the `==` equal operator here.

```
void reset() {
  Tag 0
  STUNDEN 0;
  MINUTEN 0;
  SEKUNDEN 0;
  MULTIRSEK 1; //Multiplikator für die Sekunden
  MULTIMIN 1; //Multiplikator für die Minuten
  MULTISTU 1; //Multiplikator für die Stunden
```

Here you are missing the assignment operator `=` in every line.

Please understand that there are too many issues with your code to provide a better answer here. I suggest you read a C++ book or at least do a few tutorials until you understand every keyword you're about to use.

Comment: Da ich gesehen habe das du Deutsch kannst, ich bin erst ganz am Anfang und dachte vielleicht ist es nur ein dummer Fehler den ich nicht sehe und hab ein kleinen Stubs gebraucht um meine auch teilweise unfassbar dummen und leicht zu erkennenden Fehler zu erkennen wie das mit dem ==.
Danke und schönen Tag.

Comment: lern erstmal die Grundlagen. Datentypen, Operatoren, Kontrollstrukturen usw. Dann fällt es dir auch viel leichter coole Projekte mit Mikrocontrollern umzusetzen. Das macht sich schnell bezahlt und erspart dir jede Menge Kopfschmerzen

Comment: Und ich habe MULTISEK verwendet um den Multiplikator zu verwenden um Minuten zu erkennen. Da es ja 60 sekunden, 120 sekunden,.... habe ich mir gedacht das ich einfach die 60 Sekunden mal der Anzahl der Multiplikatoranzahl zu nehmen um da die Sekundenanzahl rauszubekommen um die nächst Minute zu erkennen.
Ich hätte auch Minuten(Danke hab ich in der Sekunde als ich geantwortet habe realisiert) nehmen können hab ich aber nicht geschnallt.